# Can someone verify my approach to this question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, atomic-physics

I just started quantum mechanics I in my university. I wanted to get some practice early on and I found this problem on MIT's quantum mechanics course.
The problem goes something like this;

Show that for a non-relativistic electron the energy $∆E$ lost per revolution is small compared to the electron’s kinetic energy $K$, Using the Larmor equation.
$$ \frac{dE}{dt} = -\frac{2e^{2}a^{2}}{3c^{3}}.$$
The hint was to compute $\frac{∆E}{K}$. Following this I came up with this approach.

First I thought coming up with an equation for $E$ using the larmor equation so I integrated w.r.t t

$$E = -\frac{2e^{2}a^{2}}{3c^{3}}t$$

I substituted $a$ with $\frac{e^{2}}{r^{2}m_{e}}$, where $m_{e}$ is the mass of the electron.

Similarly I wanted to get an expression for K (kinetic Energy) and I did so by replacing E as $E_{K} + E_{P}$

$$K = E - P = -\frac{2e^{6}}{3c^{3}r^{4}m_{e}^{2}}+ \frac{e^{2}}{r} $$

After a few simplifications and computing $\frac{∆E}{K}$ I got,

$$ \frac{∆E}{K} = -\frac{2e^{4}(t-t_{2})}{2e^{4}t - r^{3}} $$

Where $t$ & $t_{2}$ are 2 different points in time.

Is my approach correct? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem #1: Your result isn’t dimensionless. (This alone tells you it is wrong.) Problem #2: Your result is a function of two times. It should just be a number. (For example: it loses 0.012% of its energy per revolution). Problem #3: That number should be expressed in terms of fundamental physical constants, not quantities like $t$, $t_2$, and $r$, especially when $t_2$ is so vague.

Comment: By the way, I have never seen $P$ used for potential energy, but maybe that is country-dependent. For me, $P$ is power or maybe momentum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get to use Bohr's model of the hydrogen atom to solve this question. The important results are the angular momentum rule and:
$$r_n = \frac{n^2}{Z} a_0 \text{   and } E_n=-\frac{k_ee^2}{2a_0}.(\frac{Z^2}{n^2})$$
where all the terms have their usual meanings, and $a_0$ is the Bohr radius. Their derivations can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model)

If you rewrite the Larmor equation as $$\frac{dE}{dt}=-\beta.a^2$$
you can substitute the acceleration '$a$' with $\frac{k_ee^2}{r^2.m_e}$. Integrating the D.E gives: $$\Delta E = -\beta.a^2.\Delta t$$

Because the question requires the energy lost per revolution, you can substitute $\frac{2\pi r_n}{v_n}$ for $\Delta t$ (the time period for one revolution) to find $\Delta E$, and the kinetic energy $K$ can be found from its definiton; $K=\frac{1}{2}m.v_n^2$. The ratio $\frac{\Delta E}{K}$ can then be found.

(In order to find $v_n$ in the above method, you can use Newton's laws in the radial direction:$m_e.v_n^2/r_n = k_e.e^2/r_n^2$)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Minor nit: From the form of the Larmor formula, the problem is using Gaussian units where $k_e=1$.